# Converting formdata type string into JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax to send FormData and receiving the output in the following format

> Result=A&Status=Approved&Error=&ErrorCode=00000

I want to convert the same into a JS object (key value pair)
e.g.

> {Result: "A", Status: "Approved", Error: "", ErrorCode: "00000"}

I can do that using string split and other string functions or regex but since the output format is consistent i was wondering if this is a known data type and if yes is there a way to convert it using native functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` in conjunction with the `URLSearchParams` constructor.

```js
const obj = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(
    'Result=A&Status=Approved&Error=&ErrorCode=00000'));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Since the data was not retrieved from the url, I never looked at it like GET parameters. URLSearchParams works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [new URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams), it should be a way better solution than string manipulation.